# Default error page in SSRS 2008

Tags: iis-7, http, asp.net, ssrs, 503-error

We are using SSRS 2008.

Is there a way to show a default error page if there is an error in the Reporting Services? 
If so how do I go about doing this?

Currently getting the following error.....

> **Service Unavailable**
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

When this error comes up I want to do a page re-direct to another page with a nice Message on it.

Answer (score 1):

The ReportManager web UI for SSRS is *just* Asp.Net Forms. So you have the usual options. For example:

You can use web.config and setup the `customErrors` tag to handle the appropriate uncaught exceptions in the ReportManager application.

Additionally, you could do what I did: Create your own `IHttpModule` and use the `Init(HttpApplication context)` method to hookup your own `EventHandler` to the `HttpContext.Error` event. From there, you can capture the underlying exception, decide what to do about it, and generate your own nice message. You could even go so far as to do a `Server.Transfer` to a custom .aspx page to make it easier to craft a nice message---instead of embedding your Html directly in your code.

This approach works in SSRS 2008 as well as SSRS 2012.